Complex audio mixdowns and mappings with FFmpeg
Looking for a way to use FFmpeg to take a single video file with 10 - 20 audio tracks and generate a series of video copies each with a different configuration of audio mixing and mapping.
For example
Say we have an Input.mxf where audio 1-8 is dialogue (each mono), 9-16 is SFX (each mono), 17-20 is temp music (odds are stereo left, evens are stereo right), 21-24 is final score (again, odds are left, evens are right)
We want to create an Output.mov with 4 audio tracks where a1 = Dialogue, a2 = SFX, a3 = Music (final only, stereo left), a4 = (Music, final only, stereo right), and temp music gets ignored.
Is there an FFmpeg command that could that could generate the Input.mov from the above Output.mxf?
I've tried a few -filter_complex and -map approaches including amix, amerge, join, pan etc etc.  Looking for a logic that can achieve any audio config that can be dreamed up.
